# Exclude all records below specific row

Tags: r, dataframe

The data I have contain three variable with three unique IDs and each has multiple records. See below

```
ID <- c(rep(1,7), rep(2,6), rep(3,5), rep(4,6))
t <- c(seq(1,7), seq(1,6), seq(1,5), rep(2,6))
y <- c(rep(6,7), rep(1,6), rep(6,5), rep(0.2,6))
z <- c(5,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,4,2,NaN,0,1,0,0,1,Inf,Inf, Inf)
dat1 <- data.frame(ID, t, y, z)
```

For each ID, if the value of z is below 0 (negative), NaN, Inf, or -Inf, I need to exclude that record AND all the records below it.

For this data, the new processed data look like:

```
ID <- c(rep(1,7), rep(2,2), rep(3,2), rep(4,3))
t <- c(seq(1,7), seq(1,2), seq(1,2), rep(2,3))
y <- c(rep(6,7), rep(1,2), rep(6,2), rep(0.2,3))
z <- c(5,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,4,2,0,0,1)
dat2 <- data.frame(ID, t, y, z)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ave`, as a group-by substitute. Using a `cumsum` counter to then identify any subsequent rows for deletion:

```
dat1[with(dat1, ave(z < 0 | (!is.finite(z)), ID, FUN=cumsum) == 0),]
```

Quick check to see they match, with the exception of rownames not lining up:

```
all.equal(
  dat2,
  dat1[with(dat1, ave(z < 0 | (!is.finite(z)), ID, FUN=cumsum) == 0),],
  check.attributes=FALSE
)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Essentially the same with `cummin` is `dat1[as.logical(ave(dat1$z, dat1$ID, FUN=function(x) cummin(is.finite(x) & x >= 0))),]`. Could be cleaned up a bit by matching your arguments closer.

Answer (score 2):

If your `ID` column is sorted in ascending order you can do this with

```
dat2 <- dat1[unlist(tapply(dat1$z, dat1$ID, function(x) 
             cumsum(x<0 | x %in% c(NaN, -Inf, Inf))==0)),]

dat2
   ID t   y z
1   1 1 6.0 5
2   1 2 6.0 0
3   1 3 6.0 0
4   1 4 6.0 0
5   1 5 6.0 1
6   1 6 6.0 0
7   1 7 6.0 0
8   2 1 1.0 0
9   2 2 1.0 0
14  3 1 6.0 4
15  3 2 6.0 2
19  4 2 0.2 0
20  4 2 0.2 0
21  4 2 0.2 1
```

Comment: This relies on the ID being sorted in order though. Try it against `dat1 <- rbind( dat1[dat1$ID==2,], dat1[dat1$ID!=2,] )` and you'll see it gives some unexpected results.

Comment: Yes - `tapply` treats them as factors and sorts them. I've included a warning above.  Thanks. Your solution with `ave` is better.

Answer (score 0):

This works on your sample data. Probably not the fastest solution.

```
mutate(dat1, rownumber = 1:nrow(dat1)) -> dat1

for(i in unique(dat1$ID)) {
  firstMiss = min(filter(dat1, ID==i & 
                           (z %in% c(NaN, Inf, -Inf) |
                              z < 0))$rownumber,
                  max(filter(dat1, ID==i)$rownumber)+1,
                  na.rm=TRUE)
  dat1 <- filter(dat1, !(ID==i & rownumber >= firstMiss))
}
dat2 <- select(dat1, -rownumber)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for laffs:

```
library(dplyr)
dat1 %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
         mutate(non_positive = min(which(lead(z,1) < 0 | 
                                 !is.finite(lead(z,1)) | row_number() == n()))) %>%
         filter(row_number() <= non_positive) %>%
         select(-non_positive)

# # A tibble: 14 x 4 
# # Groups:   ID [4] 
#       ID     t     y     z 
#    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> 
#  1     1     1   6.0     5 
#  2     1     2   6.0     0 
#  3     1     3   6.0     0 
#  4     1     4   6.0     0 
#  5     1     5   6.0     1 
#  6     1     6   6.0     0 
#  7     1     7   6.0     0 
#  8     2     1   1.0     0 
#  9     2     2   1.0     0 
# 10     3     1   6.0     4 
# 11     3     2   6.0     2 
# 12     4     2   0.2     0 
# 13     4     2   0.2     0 
# 14     4     2   0.2     1
```